# Bottom Sheet dragging issue when View Pager with full screen is used

Tags: android, events, android-viewpager, touch

I am using View Pager with full screen image view inside a bottom bottom sheet and because of the dragging the bottom sheet down is not working, removing the view pager makes it work again but that is not what I want here

I tried overriding ViewPager class and manually intercept touch events but it did not work either and it somehow disabled the dragging up to expanded even as well

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public CustomViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    
    public CustomViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        else {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        else {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Bottom Sheet Layout which contains two framelayouts out of which one is a fragment container that include the viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="?attr/nowPlayerBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <include layout="@layout/now_player_mini" />

    <!-- This is a container of fragments containing view pager -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/now_player_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment's layout that contains the view pager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <!-- This is where the problem is happening -->
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/album_art_slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fontFamily="@font/light"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="?attr/fullNowPlayerTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="12pt" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fg_now_player_gradient" />

<!-- Some other layout like buttons and seekbar goes here -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and view pager layout, it only contains a full screen image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/album_art_pages_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

These booleans are already specified for the viewpager

```
albumArtViewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
albumArtViewPager.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

This is pretty much everything for bottom sheet in MainActivity

```
nowPlaying = findViewById(R.id.now_playing);
FrameLayout frameLayoutBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(frameLayoutBottomSheet);
PEEK_HEIGHT = nowPlaying.getLayoutParams().height;
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(PEEK_HEIGHT, true);
```

And my activity_main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/mainBackground">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:translationZ="2dp">

        <include layout="@layout/now_player" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/status_bar_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="?attr/colorStatusBarBackground" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the problem and I want the panel to go down when swiped down and switch pages when view is swiped left or right

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormz2.jpg)

Comment: please code the bottom sheet and all code.

Comment: I have added the all the related codes I think is enough to show the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem, it was caused by the **View** layout, setting the
***clickable*** and ***focusable*** to false fixes the problem

```
    <!-- The problem was here because the View is intercepting all the touch events and preventing the bottom sheet from going down-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        <!-- Setting clickable and focusable to false fixes the problem -->
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"

        android:background="@drawable/fg_now_player_gradient" />
```